# Capture words inside a bracket containing a specific word

Tags: regex

https://regex101.com/r/GpO5zj/3

```
\[.*?support.*?\]
```

String:

```
XT1941-4 [Type: M3B8A] [Support: NFC]

XT1941-4 [Type: M3B8A] [Some exra word Support: Blueooth]
```

I would only like to capture `[Support: NFC]` and `[Some exra word Support: Blueooth]`.

The regex pattern I crafted is giving false captures as it is capturing `[Type...]` which is not I wanted.

I'm kind of stuck on this, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use negated [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` to match Support between the square brackets.

```php
\[[^][]*\bSupport\b[^][]*]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `[^][]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `[` or `]`
- `\bSupport\b` Match Support surrounded by word boundaries to prevent being part of a larger word
- `[^][]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `[` or `]`
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eau7uR/1)

Comment: Omg you're so fast, can you briefly explain how this works?

Comment: @NubPro I have added a breakdown of the pattern and the parts.

Comment: Hey fourth bird, this doesnt seem to be working on Javascript. I'm looking into it currently

Comment: ahh you need to escape the `[` and `]`. Final regex: ```\[[^[\]]*\bSupport\b[^[\]]*]```